# Snowflake Scripting - SELECT INTO variable when no rows returned

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to determine what is the expected behaviour when SELECT INTO does not return any rows.

From [Setting Variables to the Results of a SELECT Statement](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html#setting-variables-to-the-results-of-a-select-statement):

> In a Snowflake Scripting block, you can set variables to the values in columns specified in a SELECT clause.
>
> ```
> SELECT <column1>, <column2>, ... INTO <variable1>, <variable2>, ... 
> FROM ... WHERE ...;
> ```
>
> **The SELECT statement must return a single row.**

---

Now the examples.

**Exactly one row** - works as described, variables a,b get new values

```
DECLARE 
    a INT DEFAULT 1;
    b INT DEFAULT 2;
BEGIN
   SELECT x, y
   INTO a, b
   FROM (SELECT 100 AS x, 200 AS y) s;
   
   RETURN CONCAT(a, '    ', b);
END;
-- Output
-- 100    200
```

**More than one row** - also works as expected(error):

```
DECLARE 
    a INT DEFAULT 1;
    b INT DEFAULT 2;
BEGIN
   SELECT x, y
   INTO a, b
   FROM (SELECT 100 AS x, 200 AS y
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 100 AS x, 200 AS y
        ) s;
   
   RETURN CONCAT(a, '    ', b);
END;
```

> A SELECT INTO statement expects exactly 1 returned row, but got 2.

**No rows returned** - here the output is NULL, the DEFAULT values for a and b are gone

```
DECLARE 
    a INT DEFAULT 1;
    b INT DEFAULT 2;
BEGIN
   SELECT x, y
   INTO a, b
   FROM (SELECT 100 AS x, 200 AS y) s
   WHERE 1=2;
   
   RETURN CONCAT(a, '    ', b);
END;
-- Output
-- null
```

For comparison similar setup for Oracle [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=227209b4c3193a7a5ee3fedbd6c1c4fe) and PostgreSQL [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=02f9f488777f491efea42a7ad04dadfd)

Is the assignment  of NULL values an expected behaviour or should I rather get an error like("A SELECT INTO statement expects exactly 1 returned row, but got 0.)"?

Comment: Since Snowflake Scripting is still in Preview, you may want to reach out to Snowflake directly on this question.  However, it seems to me like a better implementation to return NULLs, rather than error out, but that's just my take.  Would you want this to error out?

Comment: Hi @MikeWalton. Both approaches could be equally valid. NULL is all right as a result. We already could do: `DECLARE a INT DEFAULT 1; BEGIN a := (SELECT 1 WHERE 1=2); RETURN a; END` returning `NULL`. Question here is `NULL` the inteded output, if yes I am perfectly fine with it.

Comment: From the demos, Postgres seems to do the same than Snowflake? A similar test for Oracle — what happens if you do `select *` from a table with 0 rows? (appears inconsistent)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa The Postgress actually allows for zero rows without error, but on the other hand also allows for multiple rows choosing the first [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e930cd4bc13911e6f98fe2da0b5c39e6)

Answer (score 2):

This is great feedback for the team while the feature is in preview — I'm passing it forward to them.

In the meantime I figured out this method to force an exception if the inner select doesn't return at least 1 row:

- Add a `limit 1` to get only one row.
- `union` an extra row with a division by zero error, that will be raised if the inner query doesn't return at least one row.

```sql
DECLARE 
    a INT DEFAULT 1;
    b INT DEFAULT 2;
BEGIN
   SELECT x, y
   INTO a, b
   FROM (
       select *
       from (SELECT 100 AS x, 200 AS y) s
       --WHERE 1=2  -- test with this line uncommented
       union all 
       select 1/0, 1/0
       limit 1
   );   
   RETURN CONCAT(a, '    ', b);
END;
```

Comment: Btw, I am not necesarilly  expecting the code should return an error. If by design the output is NULL for no rows, that is fine. It would be nice to describe such case it in documenation explicitly :)

Answer (score 0):

The current SQL UDF behaves the same way:

```
create or replace table test (a int);
create function test_udf() returns number as 'select a from test';

select test_udf();
-- returns "null"
```

So I think at least it is consistent between the two. I personally believe that it is expected behaviour.